# How to migrate from ubuntu/apache2 to httpd docker image?

Tags: docker, apache, apache2, httpd.conf

So far I used the `ubuntu/apache2:2.4-22.04_beta` to run a `apache2` reverse proxy.

I added ssl certs to `/etc/apache2/ssl`, and site configuration to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

With configuration like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile ...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLCipherSuite  ...

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Location /my-api>
                ProxyPass ...
                ProxyPassReverse ...
                RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix ...
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Question: I now would like to switch to `https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/`
But how would I have to migrate those settings? Is the image exchangeable while keeping all configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key concept was to migrate all `a2enmod` to `LoadModule` statements, into `httpd.conf`. The `VirtualHost` config could be migrated 1:1. That's it.